# How can I ensure, that an asyncio future was started, before continuing?

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio

I basically want to do something like this:

```
future_started = asyncio.Event()

async def my_future():
    future_started.set()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    [...]

async def start_my_future():
    """Starts my_future() and only returns, after my_future() has been started."""

    asyncio.ensure_future(my_future())

    await future_started.wait()
    return
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to schedule a future, but make sure, that it is started, before continuing?

EDIT: I probably should've added, that I'm running Python 3.6, since a lot of changes were made to `asyncio` later.

Comment: What exactly do you **gain** by using this kind of code - what problem are you solving? `asyncio.ensure_future(my_future())` (or `asyncio.create_task()`, which should be preferred) already ensures that the future is started at the first possible opportunity. If `future_started` is literally at the start of the coroutine, then it doesn't seem to buy anything, at least not in a correctly written asyncio program.

Comment: I think that `await asyncio.sleep(0)` will guarantee that an event loop iteration will occur before the next line of code executes.  Therefore your example will work if you just remove all the code relating to the Event.  The sleep() will cause the behavior you want.

Comment: @PaulCornelius If I remove the event code, wouldn't it be possible that `my_future` is scheduled to be executed, but `start_my_future` returns before that happens, which is not what I want?

Comment: Oops, sorry I left something out.  All you need to do is to add the line `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in start_my_future, immediately after you create the future.  That ensures an event loop iteration before your function returns.  Then you can get rid of the Event code.

Comment: @PaulCornelius So does that mean, calling `await asyncio.sleep(0)` or really awaiting anything tells the async loop "Hey, run/return to any other waiting coroutine at least once before coming back to me." ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `asyncio.create_task` instead of `asyncio.ensure_future` will start it.

Comment: Do you mean, `asyncio.create_task` will make sure the Task is started before returning? Also I forgot to mention, that I'm using python-3.6. I added that to the question.